# Difference between infectivity and cell fusion abillity of Virus. (COVID 19)

Tags: virology, coronavirus, infection, membrane

I'm a computational chemist who have interest in COVID-19.

As a physical chemist, I'm lack of basic knowledge for biology.

What is the difference between 'infectivity' and 'membrane fusion activity'?

I thought that, for corona virus, infection is equal to membrane(cell) fusion, but it seems wrong idea.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: From what I read there are the concepts: there is the receptor binding, then either the S protein does active membrane fusion and genome releasing near the cell surface, or the receptor+virus is engulfed as endosome and the fusion+releasing is achieved later, closer to the ER & Golgi (where the ribosomes and the target membranes are located). You may think to the cell as a labyrinth of membranes and the virus needs to reach the correct one to do the translation and anchor its transmembrane proteins to achieve the replication and assembly. So infectivity = releasing many virions.